# How to execute shell commands in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, shell, command-line

I want to write a JavaScript function which will execute the system shell commands ([`ls`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ls) for example) and return the value.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: where would you like to execute this command, on the client or on the server?

Comment: Why did you choose the most disliked answer as the best answer? o.0

Comment: For anyone who wants to execute a command on button click, check the next.js way here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71646984/execute-server-side-shell-script-on-button-click

Answer (score 193):

I'll answer assuming that when the asker said "Shell Script" he meant a Node.js backend JavaScript. Possibly using [commander.js](https://github.com/tj/commander.js/) to use frame your code :)

You could use the [child_process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module from node's API. I pasted the example code below.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('cat *.js bad_file | wc -l',
    function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
        console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
        if (error !== null) {
             console.log('exec error: ' + error);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Except for one thing. You'll get the error "child is not a function". The call to exec() executes the command - no need to call child(). Unfortunately, the callback isn't called whenever the child process has something to output - it is called only when the child process exits. Sometimes that's OK and sometimes it's not.

Comment: To avoid callbacks, you can use [execSync](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52575123/1269037).

Comment: Who talked about a browser ? It only says JavaScript, nothing more.

Comment: @Josh How to pass credentials here (user name and password)?

Answer (score 142):

I don't know why the previous answers gave all sorts of complicated solutions. If you just want to execute a quick command like `ls`, you don't need async/await or callbacks or anything. Here's all you need - [execSync](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options):

```js
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
// import { execSync } from 'child_process';  // replace ^ if using ES modules

const output = execSync('ls', { encoding: 'utf-8' });  // the default is 'buffer'
console.log('Output was:\n', output);
```

For error handling, add a `try`/`catch` block around the statement.

If you're running a command that takes a long time to complete, then yes, look at the [asynchronous `exec`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) function.

Comment: Does execSync works with Mac, Linux and Windows commands?

Comment: Confirmed for windows. Also, I see that there's a `shell` option for specifying "Shell to execute the command with." Default: '/bin/sh' on Unix, process.env.ComSpec on Windows.

Comment: Please do not use synchronous external operations, because your server will not be able to serve other requests until it is finished.

Answer (score 74):

...few year later...

[ES6 has been accepted as a standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) and ES7 is around the corner so it deserves updated answer. We'll use ES6+async/await with nodejs+babel as an example, prerequisites are:

- [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/download/) with [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/)
- [babel](http://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#babel_cli)

Your example `foo.js` file may look like:

```
import { exec } from 'child_process';

/**
 * Execute simple shell command (async wrapper).
 * @param {String} cmd
 * @return {Object} { stdout: String, stderr: String }
 */
async function sh(cmd) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    exec(cmd, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve({ stdout, stderr });
      }
    });
  });
}

async function main() {
  let { stdout } = await sh('ls');
  for (let line of stdout.split('\n')) {
    console.log(`ls: ${line}`);
  }
}

main();
```

Make sure you have babel:

```
npm i babel-cli -g
```

Install latest preset:

```
npm i babel-preset-latest
```

Run it via:

```
babel-node --presets latest foo.js
```

Comment: If you only need to execute a quick command, all the async/await is overkill. You can just use [execSync](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52575123/1269037).

Comment: No one asked for a Node.js solution. It only says JavaScript.

Comment: @Virus721: in which JavaScript runtime do you want to execute a shell command?

Answer (score 33):

This depends entirely on the JavaScript environment.

For example, in [Windows Scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host), you do things like:

```
var shell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
shell.Run("command here");
```

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing in a Unix-like operating system such as Linux?

Comment: That's what I was looking for. It's annoying all those people talking about their Node.js. Who asked for Node.js here ? No one did.

Comment: Would you know how to get some result (say, exit code), of the newly run command?

Comment: @sighclone I answered this nearly 14 years ago, can't say I've kept up with WScript. But the docs say the Run() method returns the exit code. https://www.vbsedit.com/html/6f28899c-d653-4555-8a59-49640b0e32ea.asp

Answer (score 21):

In a nutshell:

```
// Instantiate the Shell object and invoke its execute method.
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");

var commandtoRun = "C:\\Winnt\\Notepad.exe";
if (inputparms != "") {
  var commandParms = document.Form1.filename.value;
}

// Invoke the execute method.  
oShell.ShellExecute(commandtoRun, commandParms, "", "open", "1");
```

Comment: [ActiveXObject is available only on IE browser.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11101641/activexobject-is-not-defined-and-cant-find-variable-activexobject#answer-11101655)

Comment: There seems to be a lot of hand-wringing over which web browser this is running in, but folks should realize that JavaScript is also a perfectly valid Windows shell scripting language.

Answer (score 9):

```js
function exec(cmd, handler = function(error, stdout, stderr){console.log(stdout);if(error !== null){console.log(stderr)}})
{
    const childfork = require('child_process');
    return childfork.exec(cmd, handler);
}
```

This function can be easily used like:

```js
exec('echo test');
//output:
//test

exec('echo test', function(err, stdout){console.log(stdout+stdout+stdout)});
//output:
//testtesttest
```

Comment: For some reason the commands are executed from the end. For example, the commands ```exec('echo 1'); exec('echo 2'); exec('echo 3'); exec('echo 4');``` will lead to the conclusion ```4 3 2 1```

Answer (score 8):

Note: These answers are from a browser-based client to a Unix-based web server.

**Run a command on the client**

You essentially can't. Security says only run within a browser and its access to commands and filesystem is limited.

**Run 'ls' on the server**

You can use an [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) call to retrieve a dynamic page, passing in your parameters via a [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods).

Be aware that this also opens up a security risk as you would have to do something to ensure that Mrs rouge hacker does not get your application to say run: /dev/null && rm -rf / ...

So in a nutshell, running from JavaScript is just a bad, bad idea... your mileage may vary.

Comment: You essentially can't *in a cross-browser manner.* I believe only IE has hooks into the shell (via WSript/ActiveX).

Comment: All the high vote answers assume it's run in a non-browser context, e.g. Node. The right thing is to clarify the question, not this answer.

Answer (score 8):

With NodeJS is simple like that!
And if you want to run this script at each boot of your server, you can have a look on the [forever-service](https://github.com/zapty/forever-service#prerequisite) application!

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('php main.php', function (error, stdOut, stdErr) {
    // do what you want!
});
```

Comment: To avoid callbacks, for quick commands you can use [execSync](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52575123/1269037).

Comment: what if want to run `sudo  mysql` .??
is it possible ??
if yes, how the password, it is going to ask after this command.

Answer (score 5):

Here is simple command that executes `ifconfig` shell command of Linux

```
var process = require('child_process');
process.exec('ifconfig',function (err,stdout,stderr) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("\n"+stderr);
    } else {
        console.log(stdout);
    }
});
```

Comment: To avoid callbacks, you can use [execSync](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52575123/1269037).

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, there is no built-in function, method or otherwise, in the official ECMAScript specification to run an external process. That said, extensions are allowed, see [this note](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-built-in-function) from the spec, for example:

> NOTE Examples of built-in functions include parseInt and Math.exp. A
> host or implementation may provide additional built-in functions that
> are not described in this specification.

One such "host" is *Node.js* which has the `child_process` module. Let's try this code to execute the Linux shell command `ps -aux`, saved in `runps.js`, based on the [child_process documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v17.x/api/child_process.html#child-process):

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const ps = spawn('ps', ['-aux']);

ps.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

ps.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

ps.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

Which produces the following example output, running it in [docker](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/main/README.md#how-to-use-this-image):

```
$ docker run --rm -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app node:17-bullseye node ./runps.js
stdout: USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root           1  0.0  0.8 319312 33888 ?        Ssl  11:08   0:00 node ./runps.js
root          13  0.0  0.0   6700  2844 ?        R    11:08   0:00 ps -aux

child process exited with code 0
```

The thing I like about this module, is that it's included with the Node.js distribution, no `npm install ...` needed.

If you search the Node.js code in github for `spawn` you will find references to the [implementation](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/7b8552f5078f209fd3bbb935724d81cf5705aa11/src/process_wrap.cc) in C or C++ in the engine. Modern browsers like [Firefox](https://blog.mozilla.org/javascript/) and Chrome would be reluctant to extend [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/javascript) with such features, for obvious security reasons, even if the underlying engine such as [V8](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/901b67916dc2626158f42af5b5c520ede8752da2/samples/shell.cc) supports it.

On that note, it's better not to run our container as root, let's try the above example again, adding a [random user](https://americanexpress.io/do-not-run-dockerized-applications-as-root/) this time.

```
$ docker run --rm -u 7000 -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app node:17-bullseye node ./runps.js
stdout: USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
7000           1  5.0  0.8 319312 33812 ?        Ssl  11:19   0:00 node ./runps.js
7000          13  0.0  0.0   6700  2832 ?        R    11:19   0:00 ps -aux

child process exited with code 0
```

Of course that's better but not enough. If this approach is used at all, more precautions must be taken, such as ensuring that no arbitrary user commands can be executed.

**Windows 10**

My version of Windows 10 still has [Windows Script Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/wscript) which can run JScript on the console with the `wscript.exe` or `cscript.exe` programs, i.e. no browser needed. To try it out you can open a PowerShell [Windows Terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/). Save the following code into a file which you can call  `shell.js`:

```
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine("Hallo, ECMAScript on Windows!");
WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell").run("C://Windows//system32//mspaint.exe");
```

And on the command line, run:

```
cscript .\shell.js
```

Which shows the following and opens Paint:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.812
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Hallo, ECMAScript on Windows!
```

Other variations exist. Find the documentation applicable to your preferred JavaScript [runtime environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ECMAScript_engines).

Answer (score 3):

If you are using npm you can use the shelljs package

To install: `npm install [-g] shelljs`

```
var shell = require('shelljs');
shell.ls('*.js').forEach(function (file) {
// do something
});
```

See more: https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs

Answer (score 2):

Another post on this topic with a nice jQuery/Ajax/PHP solution:

[shell scripting and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705361/shell-scripting-and-jquery)

Comment: the question specifies javascript.

Answer (score 2):

In IE, you can do this :

```
var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
shell.run("cmd /c dir & pause");
```

Comment: ActiveXObject is available only for IE browser.

Answer (score 1):

With [nashorn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_%28JavaScript_engine%29) you can write a script like this:

```
$EXEC('find -type f');
var files = $OUT.split('\n');
files.forEach(...
...
```

and run it:

```
jjs -scripting each_file.js
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const fs = require('fs');

function ls(startPath) {
    fs.readdir(startPath, (err, entries) => {
        console.log(entries);
    })
}

ls('/home/<profile_name>/<folder_name>')
```

The startPath used here is in reference with debian distro

Answer (score 0):

Js file

```
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
oShell.ShellExecute("E:/F/Name.bat","","","Open","");
```

Bat file

```
powershell -Command "& {ls | Out-File -FilePath `E:F/Name.txt}"`
```

Js file run with node namefile.js

```
const fs = require('fs')

fs.readFile('E:F/Name.txt', (err, data) => {
if (err) throw err;

console.log(data.toString());
})
```

You can also do everything in one solution with an asynchronous function.
Directly there could be security problems.