# Is there a simpler method to run sqlite with javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sqlite, shell

Here is my current plan:

1. HTML button calls jQuery function
2. [Function loads PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5705361/shell-scripting-and-jquery)
3. PHP script executes shell script
4. [shell script calls SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076984/how-do-i-save-the-result-of-a-query-as-a-csv-file)
5. SQLite runs SQL script that creates CSV
6. Webpage reads CSV

Is there a simpler method? I tried sql.js but it seems to have some [issues with csv files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34457855/does-sql-js-support-mode-and-output).

Comment: Well most access to a database requires the basic steps you mention. How to access the database differs. Did you look at a different php library to access the db to make it easier?

Comment: @epascarello I hope it does not sound too bad that I have no desire to learn php and a library...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the database stored on the server, then you aren't going to get any simpler then:

1. JavaScript sends data in HTTP request
2. Server side program constructs SQL query
3. SQL query gets run by database

You can eliminate shelling out by using a [PHP SQLite library](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php).