# Writing a latlng to a file on the computer

Tags: javascript

I made a function that can take a an address from url and return its latlng and show a marker on the address. Is there a javascript function that can write the latlng to clipboard. Thanks.

Comment: what you have done so far? show us the code

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no standard mechanism for JavaScript access to the clipboard (yet). There are various non-standard mechanisms, like Flash ([zeroclipboard](https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard) and the like), but of course they require Flash.

Comment: Agree - pragmatically, this task is going to require Flash for a while.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: +1 I think your answer suits better to the question than the mine. He's just asking if is there a javascript function which can do things, actually :)

Answer (score 1):

As [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) said in his answer and afaicr, there isn't a javascript function which can  access to the clipboard.
Anyway, if you are under Windows, you could try to combine your javascript with [`WSH`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host)
 (Windows Script Host) script and passing the latlng to the clipboard from such as script. 
Be aware you can script a WSH file using both javascript(JScript, the Microsoft Javascript flavour, it's identical to javascript, only the name changes) and VBscript in the **same file**, if you need. So you can reutilize online VBscripts which perform the access to the clipboard, and passing your variable value obtained in JScript.

Some URLs I found, just to point out the question (try to search better, even VBscript or WSH tutorials):

http://www.memosoup.com/20100126/using-the-clipboard-in-wsh.html

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33702/WSH-Clipboard-Access

http://nerds-central.blogspot.it/2007/01/using-jscript-to-paste-text-into.html

You could store the latlng values in a `Cookie`, and then read it from a `WSH` script which will perform the copy to the clipboard. In another way, you could write a simple console `.exe` program which perform the same task. You can launch them from the server side language, or from javascript, I guess.

If you're developing under Unix, you could try to search for informations about the possibility to make the above things from `Unix shell script` or in `Unix programming`.

Comment: Suggesting a Windows specific technology to a JS question isn't very helpful if you ask me.

Comment: That isn't possible I'm afraid. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880198/how-to-execute-shell-command-in-java-script

Comment: How? JS is running sandboxed inside the browser and isn't allowed to execute arbitrary code on the computer.

Comment: I was talking about other, non Windows systems. It's ok though. I just wanted to point out that it isn't a viable solution if OP wants to support other OSes.

Comment: @jurgemaister: You could copy to the clipboard by calling a WSH script from server side language, or from javascript and passing the latlng values? Or Simply setting a cookie, and read it from a WSH script and so copy to the clipboard. It seems to be a bit tricky,I know, but could be a way.