# Get file name list from remote server directory

Tags: javascript, batch-file, remote-server, activexobject

How to connect to remote server using batch file (.bat) with .Js file?

How to get pdf file names of existing pdf files of specific path
folder from  remote server ? 
                                                                                     Actually I need to get  exist pdf files on specific path of remote
 server using javascript file and check these pdf files with Product
 Master table that is exist or not.

My Pdf files are on remote server & i am using batch file to execute
 .js file in another server.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Introduction of your main issue is in [How to execute shell command in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880198/how-to-execute-shell-command-in-java-script/). Summary : If your js is in a web page, you cannot. If it is a js launched with cscript from a windows prompt, you may consider the Matt's Answer in referenced question.

Assuming your in the latter case, you need read permissions on the remote share. Then in your batch file, you will have :

```
dir /b \\server\share\specific\folder
```

You can redirect to a file if you need one as input for your product master table :

```
dir /b \\server\share\specific\folder > pdflist.txt
```