# Is it possible to execute Unix commands with an HTML file running in a Python Webkit window?

Tags: javascript, shell, webkit, qtwebkit

I am making an HTML app running inside a Python window, using QtWebkit. I want to execute a shell command and get the output.

Can it be done without using Node.js?

Comment: @dandavis The HTML file is running inside Python, so I cannot send signal from Python to HTML. But somehow, if I can run another Python file inside the HTML one then it might be done. I have no idea how to do that either.

Comment: @Cheery I am not using Node.js

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi js can not do it. Only in IE - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880198/how-to-execute-shell-command-in-java-script