# How to run .exe file or .bat file based on button click event using Javascript

Tags: javascript, batch-file

In my current project, I would like to run .bat or .exe file using button click event using JavaScript. The content of batch file is as shown below:

```
start "S:\" TemperatureSensor.exe
```

which start TemperatureSensor.exe file when TemperatureSensor button is clicked.
Code for HTML page is shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to make a BUTTON element with text.</p>

<button onclick="window.open('file:///S:/Test.bat')">Temperature Sensor</button>

</body>
</html>
```

When I clicked on Temperature Sensor button, it should run Test.bat file but it just display following in new page:

[image]

Am I missing ?? Is it possible to run .exe file using button click event??

**Updated:**
Code for HTML page is shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to make a BUTTON element with text.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Temperature Sensor</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
      var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");

var commandtoRun = "C:\\TemperatureSensor.exe";
if (inputparms != "") {
var commandParms = document.Form1.filename.value;
 }

 // Invoke the execute method.  
 oShell.ShellExecute(commandtoRun, commandParms, "", "open", "1");
 }
 </script>

 </body>
 </html>
```

When I clicked on Temperature Sensor button it displays error: **Uncaught ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined**.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880198/how-to-execute-shell-command-in-javascript

Comment: You should use a HTA to bypass the security issue

Comment: @Hackoo Could you please elaborate in detail ???

Comment: @guest271314- I got error Uncaught ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined. What should I do ??

Comment: @Saurabh13 Have you tried one of the alternative approaches at linked page ?

Comment: @Saurabh13 Check my answer !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just save this code as ***RunExe.hta*** and not ***RunExe.html*** and executes it by double click on it !

***EDIT : REMARK about (HTA) (HTML Application)***

***HTML Application (HTA)*** is a Microsoft Windows program whose source code consists of HTML, Dynamic HTML, and one or more scripting languages supported by Internet Explorer, such as VBScript or JScript.

The HTML is used to generate the user interface, and the scripting language is used for the program logic.

A HTA executes without the constraints of the internet browser security model; in fact, it executes as a "fully trusted" application.

further reading about [HTA HTML Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Run Exe or Bat files from HTA by Hackoo</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
  APPLICATIONNAME="Run Exe or Bat files from HTA by Hackoo"
  ID="MyHTMLapplication"
  VERSION="1.0"/>
</head>
<script>
function RunExe(){
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    var path = '"S:/Test.bat"';
    shell.run(path,1,false);
}
</script>
<input style="width: 170px; height:23px; color: white; background-color: #203040; 
font-family:Book Antiqua;" type="button" Value="Temperature Sensor" onClick="RunExe();"
</html>
```

Comment: @Hackoo- Thank you for the solution. Now, Can I run this code in linux ?? If not than what should I do to run such kind of code in linux ??

Comment: It work well while I run bat file. However how to run batch file with administrative privileges.

Comment: Can I use relative path to bat file? I will give the html to someone else can't be sure where they will put it on their hard drive.

Comment: is ActiveXObject only available on IE? can we use ActiveXObject in chrome? How?

Comment: @RaviMakwana You can't use chrome to execute an EXE,BAT,VBS
An HTML Application (HTA) is a Microsoft Windows program whose source code consists of HTML, Dynamic HTML, and one or more scripting languages supported by Internet Explorer, such as VBScript or JScript. The HTML is used to generate the user interface, and the scripting language is used for the program logic.An HTA executes without the constraints of the internet browser security model; in fact, it executes as a "fully trusted" application. 
further reading about [HTA HTML Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application)

Comment: this is what I want，thx

Answer (score 1):

If you're using firefox you could use this [addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/local-filesystem-links/) to open batch or exe files.

Exe and batch files aren't opening in browser by default becaue of security restrictions.

In a later version of the addon there will be an enable preference for exe-files and these files will be disabled by default.

But at the moment you can create links like `<a href="file://c:/test.bat">test</a>` and launch the file with a click.