# Running a .bat file using an HTML button

Tags: html, batch-file

I'm attempting to create a button that opens and executes a batch file so that it easier for everyone to access.

```html
<input type="button" value="Test" onclick="window.open('bat:///\\123.hello.net\FileShares\ Logon\SAPfileConfig.bat')" />
```

Whenever I execute on IE, it says that file cannot be found.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: What is the location of your batch file ?

Comment: Take a look at this [How to run .exe file or .bat file based on button click event using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104713/how-to-run-exe-file-or-bat-file-based-on-button-click-event-using-javascript?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Hi Hackoo, it's on a folder on a shared drive!

Comment: What's the UNC Path ? i don't think is like this : `bat:///` ?

Comment: I apologize that was a mistake I meant it to be file: but the UNC path is \\123.hello.net\FileShares\Logon\Config.bat

Answer (score 4):

You will not be able to execute a bat file using your web page. You may able to make it download automatically, but it will not be executed automatically for some security issue

Comment: Hi Nikhil! This isn't from a web page, it's from a file from our shared drive in which I have renamed for security purposes.

Comment: In this case, it is similar to loading from a website, you will not be able to execute it. If my answer is useful for you please accept and upvote my answer. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can try with a HTA file like this : Run Exe or Batch files with Javascript and HTA

***Javascript_Execute.hta***

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Run Exe or Batch files with Javascript and HTA</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
  APPLICATIONNAME="Run Exe or Batch files with Javascript and HTA"
  ID="MyHTMLapplication"
  VERSION="1.0"/>
</head>
<script language="Javascript">
function RunMe(){
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    var path = '"file:\\\\123.hello.net\\FileShares\\Logon\\SAPfileConfig.bat"';
    shell.run(path,1,false);
}
</script>
<input style="width: 170px; height:23px; color: white; background-color: #203040; 
font-family:Book Antiqua;" type="button" Value="Execute Batch File" onClick="RunMe();"
</html>
```

Or you can Run Exe or Batch files with Vbscript and HTA :

***Vbscript_Execute.hta***

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Run Exe or Batch files with Vbscript and HTA</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
  APPLICATIONNAME="Run Exe or Batch files with Vbscript and HTA"
  ID="MyHTMLapplication"
  VERSION="1.0"/>
</head>
<script language="Vbscript">
Function RunMe()
Dim Shell,path
Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
path = "file:\\123.hello.net\FileShares\Logon\SAPfileConfig.bat"
shell.run path,1,false
End Function
</script>
<input style="width: 170px; height:23px; color: white; background-color: #203040; 
font-family:Book Antiqua;" type="button" Value="Execute Batch File" onClick="RunMe()"
</html>
```