# Button click on teams bot should execute exe on user machine

Tags: button, bots, click, exe, microsoft-teams

I have teams bot which is developed for IT support. Currently it just shows the snapshots and video which user needs to follow the instructions. Now requirement is to execute bat file or exe on user machine when user click button on teams bot menu option. As per my understanding I need some application running at user end which should start when user click on teams bot button but not sure how this application will get trigger. Any idea will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please check if it helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-add-suggested-actions?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: This is for sending the text value of card  action which I am already doing. I need to execute exe at client end when clinet click on any of the button.

Comment: Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104713/how-to-run-exe-file-or-bat-file-based-on-button-click-event-using-javascript) thread, it explains how to run .bat or .exe file using button click.