# How can I execute a Linux shell command or script, using javaScript, html(execute button), node.js and firefox browser on Linux OS?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, linux, firefox

How can I execute a Linux shell command or script, using javaScript, html(execute button), node.js and firefox browser on Linux OS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute shell command in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880198/how-to-execute-shell-command-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML page would have to send a request to your Node.js program, either using an HTML form submission or an AJAX request or WebSocket and your Node.js program would have to run the script or command using the `child_process` module.

See: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: I’m very new on this, would you please give me a link to a github project? Thank you.