# Gnome Extensions - Run shell command

Tags: javascript, shell, gnome, gnome-shell-extensions, gjs

I am writing a simple extension to open browser by clicking the extension button. I would like to know if there is a function which can execute passed shell command as argument. Also, it'd be really helpful if anyone can suggest a good simple reference for extension development.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20638212/5725669)

Answer (score 10):

From https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/master/js/misc/util.js:

```
// Runs @command_line in the background, handling any errors that
// occur when trying to parse or start the program.
function spawnCommandLine(command_line) {
    try {
        let [success, argv] = GLib.shell_parse_argv(command_line);
        trySpawn(argv);
    } catch (err) {
        _handleSpawnError(command_line, err);
    }
}
```

There are a few variations on that method in there. Save yourself mountains of headaches and just bookmark the GitHub repository.

Some quick links:

- [popupMenu.js](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/master/js/ui/popupMenu.js): working with popup menus
- [panel.js](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/master/js/ui/panel.js): a good read for implementing "tray" icons
- [modalDialog.js](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/master/js/ui/modalDialog.js): some UI elements were made to be reused, runDialog.js uses this for example
- [mpris.js](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/master/js/ui/mpris.js): there are also good examples of using frameworks like DBus in gjs

I can't stress enough how much you'll get out of reading the gnome-shell source. Unfortunately, it's compiled into a resource file now so we don't have local copies to stumble upon.

**UPDATE (2021)**

If you're reading this, please instead see the documentation available on [gjs.guide](https://gjs.guide). Specifically the documentation on [Spawning Subprocesses](https://gjs.guide/guides/gio/subprocesses.html), which covers why this is a bad idea in extensions and how to do it slightly less bad.

Comment: I'm missing a way to use these functions in my extension without copy & paste. Is there any?

Comment: You just import them as modules then instantiate or subclass the Classes and call the functions: `const Util = imports.misc.util; Util.spawnCommandLine("...");`

Comment: What should be done if the command requires `sudo`? Do you include `sudo` in your command, or will Gnome ask for password window-style?

Comment: If it's not a GUI program that can request permissions itself, you should first examine whether that's a good idea since your user may not have feedback as to the results. But if you're sure it's a good idea, you would probably have to use `pkexec` or maybe `gksudo`.

Comment: @andy.holmes any idea how to get the output of the bash command we spawn?

Comment: @kartheek7895 Use Gio.Subprocess instead: https://andyholmes.github.io/articles/subprocesses-in-gjs.html#communicating-with-processes

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, `communicate_utf8(stdin_buf, cancellable)` does the job for me

Comment: I think you should add the usage information (imports + invoking `Utils` functions) to the answer, as it is not obvious that these functions should be just imported without reading the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not interested in the result - i.e. when you want to open a browser window - you can just use GLib.spawn_command_line_async like so:

```
const GLib = imports.gi.GLib;
...
(this._menuEntries[i]).connect('activate', () => {
       GLib.spawn_command_line_async('firefox http://example.com?p='+ my_params[i]);
});
```

If you need a synchronous result, read https://gjs.guide/guides/gio/subprocesses.html