# Is there some jsp script that will open the command prompt for Windows?

Tags: javascript, jsp, cmd

My group and I are working on a project where we are creating a locally hosted webpage and are trying to open command terminal and run a command within the script of our jsp for one of our pages.

We haven't been able to find any script that will actually open the command terminal nevermind run a line of code in it.

Is this possible to open the command terminal through our script?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: no, there isn't.

Comment: Are you just trying to run a process, or does it need to be in command prompt?

Comment: @jrtapsell We are trying to run a .py file through our command terminal. So we click a button on our web page and it opens the command terminal and runs the command to open our .py file. Not sure this is the best way to do this but we cant find another option.

Comment: You want the code to run on the server or the client?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't without an ActiveX (for Windows) or something like this (an external component).
Take a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880198/how-to-execute-shell-command-in-javascript).