# get gulp version in gulpfile

Tags: javascript, gulp

Is there a way to detect what version of Gulp is running (available to utilize in a gulpfile)?

I've got two separate gulpfile's I'm using amongst different environments, some that require v3 and some v4.  For easier version control, I would prefer it if I could combine those files and not have to deal with different file names in different environments to eliminate confusion between multiple developers. Obviously to accomplish this I would need the script to differentiate between versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively to @alireza.salemian's solution, you could try to run the command line version command in javascript:

Depending on your JavaScript backend, your code may vary slightly, but inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880198/how-to-execute-shell-command-in-javascript/52575123#52575123) you could run it as below:

```
    const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
    // import { execSync } from 'child_process';  // replace ^ if using ES modules
    const output = execSync('gulp -v', { encoding: 'utf-8' });  // the default is 'buffer'
    const str_pos = output.search('Local version') + 14;
    const gulp_version = output.substring( str_pos, str_pos + 5 );
    console.log( 'Gulp version: ' + gulp_version );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read package.json and find gulp version

```
const pkgJson = fs.readFileSync('./package.json', { encoding: 'utf8' });
const pkg = JSON.parse(pkgJson);
const gulpVersion = pkg['devDependencies']['gulp'];
```

It may not be the best solution, but you can quickly determine the gulp version.