# Running shell command on SvelteKit app startup

Tags: javascript, typescript, shell, vite, sveltekit

I want to execute pocketbase.sh shell command at SvelteKit application which uses Vite, on startup. Do you have any ideas how do I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the best way to do this is within your `package.json`. In there you will see (among others) the `dev` script with something like `vite dev`. In order to run this script on startup, just ensure it runs before the original command. For example, something like this:

```bash
sh ./pocketbase/pocketbase.sh && vite dev
```

This will get you covered for the dev environment. As per the prod environment (if needed), you will need to figure it out what command you need and do the same. For example, as I use the node adapter, the command I use to run the project is `node build/index.js` so, if this was also yours, you could add the `prod` command into your `package.json` like this:

```bash
sh ./pocketbase/pocketbase.sh && node build/index.js
```

And then you could run it with `npm run prod`.

Other options would be to execute a command from [javascript itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880198/how-to-execute-shell-command-in-javascript) but I think running it from `package.json` is far better and simpler.

Answer (score 0):

## I'm using [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently)

`pnpm/npm -D install concurrently`

```json
{
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "concurrently \"vite dev --host\" \"cd backend && go run main.go serve --http=127.0.0.1:8080\"",
        "site": "vite dev --host",
    }
}
```

Instead of my command `cd backend && go run main.go serve --http=127.0.0.1:8080` replace it with yours, because i'm using pocketbase as a framework